# Performing an Arcpy code using Python on all shapefiles in a folder or geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I have a geodatabase with many polyline feature classes all with different names. I would like to write a code in python ArcGIS 10.1 to use a geoprossing tool on all classes in the gdb. How would this be done?

Would the same logic work for a folder of shapefiles?

For this question lets say I want to use `Create Random Points` 500 metres apart on all polylines in this gdb.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\Example.gdb"

arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_Management (
```

I asked a similar question on Stack Overflow, except using VBA to loop through a folder of excel workbooks.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022672/looping-a-code-through-a-folder-of-workbooks-with-vba

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "E:\Example.gdb"

# here you are creating a list of all features from your workspace
lst = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "Polyline")

# and here you are looping
for featureClass in lst:
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_Management(
```

Comment: Don't use "list" as a variable name (i.e. `list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "Polyline")`). A list is a python built-in type.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply set my workspace (arcpy.env.workspace = "NAME OF GDB HERE") and then list the Line feature classes into a python list (fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","Polyline")).  Then you can loop through them.

So same as other answer provided but with 1 minor difference - incorporating the Polyline option:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Your.gdb"

# Create list of all polyline feature classes
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "Polyline")

for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_Management(
```

Some documentation here:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000018000000